# Tika performance 1.9

Tags: performance, apache-tika

We are using tika 1.9 library to extract content. The system processes incoming data and extracts its content. 
To improve the performance we, have 100 threads which actually extract data from tika. Though if we bump up the threads beyond 100, there is no further performance improvement.

We use the same instance of AutoDetectParser across the threads, could that cause a bottle neck?

Also, is there anything in tika which can be fine tuned to improve the performance of content extraction.

We also tried the same exercise with tika 1.15 but again there wasn't any gain in performance.

Regards,
Gaurav

Comment: How many cores does your system have? You won't really get much more performance with more threads than cores for most Tika Parsers

Comment: We have 8 cores and 32 GB on the system.

Comment: You probably only want to run something like 10-20 threads then

Comment: thanks for the advice, through my concern is that with 8 cores and 100 threads the total CPU usage is still around 30% , I haven't maxed out on CPU usage.